# Insert form shifts to the left after running the AMU.loadRecordByKey function

Tags: google-app-maker

I am calling AMU.loadRecordByKey(widget) in the onAttach event of an edit form (not an insert form) to display the correct record that was previously submitted.

Here is the function from the App Maker University script library:

```
/**
 * Loads a record by Key
 * Checks URL first and then uses page parameter RECORD_ID
 * Use in the page onAttach, recommend a deticated datasource
 * @param {Object} widget Should be the page
 */
AMU.loadRecordByKey = function(widget){
  google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
    var recordId = location.parameter.record_id;
    var properties = app.pages[app.currentPage.name].properties;
    if (recordId !== undefined && recordId !== null) {
      widget.datasource.query.filters._key._equals = recordId;     
    }else if(properties.RECORD_ID !== null){
      widget.datasource.query.filters._key._equals = properties.RECORD_ID;     
    }else{
    //  alert('No Record ID Found'); 
    }   
    widget.datasource.load();    
  });
};
```

When the form initially opens its displays fine, but right after the AMU function is called, everything on the form shifts to the left. There is no error in the function (I tested this by putting alerts between every line).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The script just loads datasource. Once items are loaded rendering engine does its work. So, there is nothing to do with the script, you need to look at your layout.

Keep in mind, that ideally you need to use this script with datasource in manual load mode, to avoid double data loading and blinking.

**Side note:**

```js
// this
var properties = app.pages[app.currentPage.name].properties;

// can be simplified to this
var properties = app.currentPage.properties;
```

Comment: Thanks, you're a life saver.  Yes, I created a new datasource just for the insert form that has the Manual save mode button enabled.